# Computing weights for multi-site RCT

Tags: r, plyr, weighted-average

Assume a multisite RCT with two groups — experimental and control.  Weights need to be computed for each time period and site.  I am fixing the weights for experimental subjects to 1, and then computing weights for the control subject so the sum of the control group weights are equal to the sum of the experimental group weights (for each time period and site).  Here is code to generate a hypothetical data set:

```
set.seed(13458) # Set random seed
ID <- c(1:20)  # Generate 20 unique subject IDs 
timePeriod <- c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 6), rep(3, 11)) # Generate time periods
site <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 6), rep("C", 11)) # Generate sites
group <- sample(c("exp", "cont"), 20, replace = TRUE) # Random assignment
outcome <- sample(c(rep(0,75), 0:100), 20, replace = TRUE) # Generate outcomes 
DF <- data.frame(ID, timePeriod, site, group, outcome) # Create a data frame
```

And the output:

```
head(DF)
    ID timePeriod site group outcome
1   1          1    A  cont      12
2   2          1    A  cont      37
3   3          1    A   exp      59
4   4          2    B   exp       0
5   5          2    B  cont       0
6   6          2    B   exp       0
7   7          2    B  cont       0
8   8          2    B   exp      22
9   9          2    B   exp      34
10 10          3    C  cont      26
```

Here is a rather clumsy strategy for computing weights for experimental and control subjects for each time period and site.

```
library(plyr)
a <- ddply(DF, c("timePeriod", "site", "group"), function(x){
     countSubjects <- length(x$group)
     data.frame(N = countSubjects)     
     })

a$weight <- rep(NA, nrow(a)) for(i in 1:nrow(a))
     {
     n <- a$N[i+1]
     d <- a$N[i]
     weight <- n/d
     a$weight[i] <- ifelse(a$group[i] == "cont", weight, 
                         ifelse(a$group[i] == "exp", 1, a$ratio))
     }

> print(a)
  timePeriod site group N weight
1          1    A  cont 2    0.5
2          1    A   exp 1    1.0
3          2    B  cont 2    2.0
4          2    B   exp 4    1.0
5          3    C  cont 5    1.2
6          3    C   exp 6    1.0
>
```

How can I take these weights to compute adjusted outcomes (i.e., multiplying the outcomes for each subject by the respective weight for the time period, site, and group)?  My interest is to add the computed weights and the adjusted outcomes to the original data frame.  (Here is an example of the adjusted outcomes.)

```
ID 1:  12 * .5 = 6
ID 2:  37 * .5 = 18.5
ID 3:  59 * 1 = 59 
ID 4:  0 * 1 = 0
…
ID 8:  22 * 1 = 22
…
ID 10: 26 * 1.2 = 31.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dplyr it can be done like this:

```
tmp <- DF %>% group_by(timePeriod, site, group) %>% mutate(N=n(), outcome)
tmp %>% group_by(timePeriod, site) %>% 
  arrange(group) %>%
  mutate(weight=ifelse(group=="cont", last(N)/first(N), last(N)/last(N)),
         adjusted=outcome*weight )
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.  After loading the dplyr library, I ran the code and I'm getting an Error "could not find function "%>%" ".  Any thoughts of why this is happening?

Comment: which version of dplyr library do you use?

Comment: I just updated to the new one:  dplyr_0.2.  After updating, the error message is "expecting a single value."

Comment: I see there are dependency issues with the order of loading plyr and dplyr.  After ordering it plyr and then dplyr, the error is: "Error in n(): This function should not be called directly."

Comment: with `library(plyr); library(dplyr)` everything should be ok

Comment: Do `detach("package:plyr", unload=TRUE)`